# gganimate animations are laggy and not smooth

Tags: r, animation, gganimate

I have been trying to learn how to use gganimate to animate plots. I was following the vignette (at https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html#enter-and-exit) and when I tried to replicate the codes given there, I don't get the same results (as given on the page). 
When I run the code given below, I get the .gif given here. Compare it to the one on the page.

```
anim <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species), size = 2) + 
  transition_states(Species,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 1)

anim + 
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink()
```

GIF: https://media.giphy.com/media/KzKXtbWUUbisIc36n2/giphy.gif (saved using `anim_save(filename="mygif.gif"`)

As you see, the .gif is laggy as hell. When I try to modify it using height, width, res etc. using the code below, I get the next .gif.

```
animate(anim, res=250, height = 1080, width = 1980)
```

GIF: https://media.giphy.com/media/l51eJwWo0rj1OpzubE/giphy.gif (saved using `anim_save(filename="mygif2.gif"`)

Still laggy and not smooth. I have the latest versions of ggplot2, gganimate, tweenr, transformr. What should I do? How can I get silky smooth gifs? Please help.